# Autotext for Windows 7

Tags: winapi, autocomplete, visual-c++-2010

'm creating a small accessibility feature in Visual C++ 2010 that I will use for myself for replacing bits of text anywhere within Windows 7. Something similar to the AutoText feature in Word. It should replace whole words only too.
For example, replace u with you but should not have you as yoyou. When the user types the first few letters of a known word or sentence that is stored in the autotext, i want to replace it with something.

I don't want a console program but a small application that runs in the background, perhaps in the tray that whenever its not needed, i can just quit it and it would stop matching.

I am learning Win32 programming and I am a fairly good at programming so any tips for me on what API/classes I can jump directly to and learn first.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probbaly get the information and events you want using CBT hooks and/or the accessability APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of such programs available for such purpose already.

Try http://www.autotext-software.com or http://www.phraseexpress.com (This is a Autotext power tool). Both are free.